# How to convert json dataframe to normal dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe which has lots of json datas inside.

for example :

```
{"serial": "000000001fb105ea", "sensorType": "acceleration", "data": [1603261123.328814, 0.171875, -0.9609375, 0.0234375]}
{"serial": "000000001fb105ea", "sensorType": "acceleration", "data": [1603261125.0605137, 0.0859375, -0.984375, 0.0]}
{"serial": "000000001fb105ea", "sensorType": "strain", "data": [1603261126.3532753, 0.9649793604217437]}
{"serial": "000000001fb105ea", "sensorType": "acceleration", "data": [1603261127.6988888, 0.0390625, -1.0, 0.125]}
{"serial": "000000001fb105ea", "sensorType": "acceleration", "data": [1603261128.8530502, 0.078125, -0.9921875, 0.0]}
```

There are two types of data.Strain sensor and acceleration sensor.

I want to parse these json datas and convert to normal form. I just need data part of json objects.At result I should have 4 columns for every values in Data.

```
Date: 21.20.2020:09:18:46    x:0.171875     y:-0.9609375    z:0.0234375
```

I tried json_normalize but I got this error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'itervalues'
```

How to parse data part to 4 column dataframe ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If input data are in `json` file use:

```
cols = ['Date','x','y','z']
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json('json.json', lines=True)['data'].tolist(), columns=cols)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='s')
print (df)
                           Date         x         y         z
0 2020-10-21 06:18:43.328814030  0.171875 -0.960938  0.023438
1 2020-10-21 06:18:45.060513735  0.085938 -0.984375  0.000000
2 2020-10-21 06:18:46.353275299  0.964979       NaN       NaN
3 2020-10-21 06:18:47.698888779  0.039062 -1.000000  0.125000
4 2020-10-21 06:18:48.853050232  0.078125 -0.992188  0.000000
```

If input is `DataFrame` with column `col`:

```
cols = ['Date','x','y','z']
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(df['col'])['data'].tolist(), columns=cols)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='s')
print (df)
                           Date         x         y         z
0 2020-10-21 06:18:43.328814030  0.171875 -0.960938  0.023438
1 2020-10-21 06:18:45.060513735  0.085938 -0.984375  0.000000
2 2020-10-21 06:18:46.353275299  0.964979       NaN       NaN
3 2020-10-21 06:18:47.698888779  0.039062 -1.000000  0.125000
4 2020-10-21 06:18:48.853050232  0.078125 -0.992188  0.000000
```

EDIT:

Personally save csv like `.xls` is not good idea, because then `read_excel` raise weird error, but you can use:

```
import ast

df = pd.read_csv('15-10-2020-OO.xls')

cols = ['Date','x','y','z']

data = [x['data'] for x in df['Data'].apply(ast.literal_eval)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='s')
print (df)
                              Date         x         y         z
0    2020-10-15 07:21:16.159236193  0.085938 -0.972656  0.003906
1    2020-10-15 07:21:17.597931385  0.089844 -0.968750  0.003906
2    2020-10-15 07:21:18.838171959  0.089844 -0.972656  0.003906
3    2020-10-15 07:21:20.338105917  0.085938 -0.972656  0.003906
4    2020-10-15 07:21:21.768864155  0.089844 -0.984375  0.003906
                           ...       ...       ...       ...
8457 2020-10-15 08:59:57.907007933  0.085938 -0.972656  0.003906
8458 2020-10-15 08:59:58.371274233  0.089844 -0.976562  0.003906
8459 2020-10-15 08:59:58.833237648  0.085938 -0.976562  0.003906
8460 2020-10-15 08:59:59.313337088  1.517057       NaN       NaN
8461 2020-10-15 08:59:59.863240004  0.089844 -0.968750  0.007812

[8462 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: No, input datas are in csv file.Can you edit for csv ? Thanks :)

Comment: @notNowOnlyCoding - How looks csv file? Is possible change `json.json` to `file.csv` ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/9G9h85f   It is just like that. Is there any solution ?

Comment: @notNowOnlyCoding - second paragraph of my answer?

Comment: https://ibb.co/r77vGZ2   This KeyError occured.Any idea ? df is a dataframe before your code in picture.

Comment: @notNowOnlyCoding - try change `col` to `Data` - `df = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(df['Data'])['data'].tolist(), columns=cols)`

Comment: "   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'  " This error occured then.

Comment: @notNowOnlyCoding - So it means problem with data, are confidental? If not, please share csv by dropbox, wetranser, gdocs...

Comment: @notNowOnlyCoding - Please share my one file, now I get `You need access`

Comment: Any idea ? Will you help me ?

Comment: @notNowOnlyCoding - sorry, a bit busy

Comment: @notNowOnlyCoding - I got `XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'Data\n"{"'`, if I use `df = pd.read_excel('15-10-2020-OO.xls')`, for you it working?

Comment: Okay then , I will be very happy if you can take a look at the opportunity.Thanks

Comment: @notNowOnlyCoding - Input file is excel? Or csv? For you working reading excel to dataframe? Or not?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('15-10-2020-OO.csv') with this code yeah it is working